# php returns a whole html file instead of a string (ajax)

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I'm working on a website which uses AJAX and I've run into a dead end. My javascript has a function named validate which takes from the "name" and "password" fields and sends it over to php, waiting for a response.

```
function Validate() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {

        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {

            if (xmlhttp.responseText.value == 'Invalid'){

                $("#box").effect('shake',150);  

                document.getElementById("validationText").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
            else if (xmlhttp.reponseText.value == 'Success!'){  
            console.log(xmlhttp.responseText.value)
                document.getElementById("validationText").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;


            }
        }
    }

    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    var arg = "JqueryPhp.php?name=" + name + "&password=" + password;

    xmlhttp.open("GET", arg, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

The php file should return either "Success!" or "Invalid" depending on the situation.

```
<?php

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");

    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

      mysql_select_db("collegedatabase", $con);

      $getUserName = $_GET["name"];
      $getPassword = $_GET["password"];

      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `admin`");
      $Success = false;

      /*    if the user entered does not exist, run the function which shakes the screen and add a bit of text to say that the username is invalid  */

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            if ($row['userName'] == $getUserName && $row['password'] == $getPassword){
                echo "Success!";
                $Success = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if($Success === false) {
            echo ('Invalid');
        }


    ?>
```

Instead, it returns a whole html file, with the string inside of a body tag. the response which I recorded from firebug is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>



<body>

Invalid</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us the php file?

Comment: We can't really help without seeing the code that generates the output.

Comment: Just don't echo it through a template, and place a json header on it and parse that.

Comment: I'd change to Jquery.ajax http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and specify datatype:text, or better still use JSON.

Comment: @Waygood why do you assume the OP is using jQuery?

Comment: Sorry about the bold font, I'm new at this and I thought it would help to make it more readable as there's so much text. The php didn't show up initially, but I've fixed it.

Comment: @Neal not sure he is assuming the OP is using JQuery, but probably assuming the OP should be switching to JQuery.

Comment: I've used a jquery function to cause the log in box to shake, but I'd prefer to use JavaScript for the bulk of the ajax part so I understand what's going on first. I haven't used JSON, and I'll check it out, but is there any fix for the whole "html page" problem?

Comment: $("#box").effect('shake',150); but not using $.ajax();

Comment: Fundamentally, your page is being templated - are you using a framework like CodeIgniter/similar?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing this because I want to learn JavaScript. The box shake is just for some aesthetics on the side. I've learnt a bit of jquery before, but that was before javascript and I want to learn the language.

Comment: just a suggestion to your php code here. Instead of looping through all rows of `admin`, put the username and password in for the criteria in the where clause. and use [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) to check if there's a match. `echo (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) ? "Invalid" : "Success!";`

Comment: $.ajax({
     url: JqueryPhp.php?name="+name+"&password="+password,
     cache: false,
     dataType: 'json',
     async: false,
     timeout: 5000
 });  // suggested because simple entires for cache, timeout, datatype returned etc....

Comment: @user1301840 with $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE username='".mysql_real_escape_string($getUserName)."' AND password='".mysql_real_escape_string($getPassword)."'");

Comment: @ edd slipszenko dreamweaver had included html around my php by default, I didn't realize that it would come with the echo, but I've removed it, so now the echo only sends "Invalid" or "Success". thanks for your advice, anyways

Comment: @Waygood thanks for adding that part, I was feeling lazy

Comment: Thank everyone for your help, I've managed to get the echo to return the value I needed. I didn't expect so many responses in so little a time. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put an `exit;` at the end of your PHP code.

You probably have something running at the end that is causing a full html page to render.

Comment: Upon reading your answer I had a look at the php file, and it turn out that I had html around the php, which was the html being generated. (added by default to php files made in dreamweaver) Now, fireBug returns the intended "Invalid" or "Success!", which is perfect, but the if statement in the javascript doesn't pick it up. for all intents and purposes though, you've solved the original problem, thanks :)

Answer (score -5):

I recommend you use Jquery Function $.POST

```
$.post("URL.php",{
       //Params(post)
    },
     function(data){
         //Answer  (data)
    })
```

Comment: Where did the jQuery come from? And how would that change **anything**?

Comment: [jQuery solves all kinds of browser problems](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)

Comment: this is a native function of the jquery  comes from jquery library
is very easy to work.
the response may come as json or string